# Custom robot dashboard

Tags: qt, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a simple way to build virtual dashboard (teach pendant) for industrial robot.

What I basically need is a GUI application with several buttons where I can emulate such things like emergency button, dead man's handle, axes selection and actuation, and others.

[rqt_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure) is not an option since buttons are not supported.

Probably the [rqt_robot_dashboard](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_robot_dashboard) is what I need, but unfortunatelly there are neither tutorials nor documentation available. The link to Python API docs is broken either.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I am on ROS Indigo now.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210513/custom-robot-dashboard/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2015-06-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The API link is broken indeed, but you can get the some docs at:
http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rqt_robot_dashboard/html/

Furthermore, it is maybe worthwhile to look at other robots' dashboards and take and adapt the existing bits and pieces, e.g. the youbot dashboard:
https://github.com/youbot/youbot-ros-pkg/tree/master/youbot_diagnostics/youbot_dashboard

or the turtlebot dashboard: https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_desktop/tree/indigo/kobuki_dashboard

---

Originally posted by [daenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/3203/daenny/) with karma: 376 on 2015-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-03**:
I somehow think the dashboards are not really nice everybody is reinventing the wheel, there is nothing really reusable. For example everybody does it's own diagnostics message for the laptop battery while there would be actually a node like laptop_battery_monitor in ros-drivers ...

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-03**:
Maybe a reconfigurable widget for a single or multiple buttons would be nice, and having a rqt_button message... or something like that...

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-06-04**:
@daenny Thanks! I have seen that page with API, but was confused by empty Main page.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-06-04**:
@cyborg-x1 I agree, there should be a simpler way to define such simple things. I will try to adopt Qt Quick with its markup language (QML) it looks [very promising](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-gallery-example.html). But I am not sure if Indigo and Jade depend on Qt5.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, finally I wrote a small plugin to integrate Qt 5.4 QML with ROS: https://github.com/bgromov/ros_qml. The interface can be edited directly with Qt Designer and all the logic can be programmed with QML JavaScript.

See example [here](https://github.com/bgromov/ros_qml/blob/master/examples/main.qml).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1